# $f(x)=x/（x^2+1）$ Deduce that f is not one-to-one. State the range of f。

Tags: functions

The function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=x/(x^2+1)$, $x$ is an element of a set of real number.
If $a$ is an element of a set of real number and $a$ is not $0$, find the image of $1/a$ under $f$. (This I know how to solve it, but after that... I don't know)

Deduce that $f$ is not one-to-one.(How can we deduce?By diagram?)

Show that if $a,b$ are an element of real number with $a>b≥1$,then $f(b)>f(a)$.

Deduce that, if the domain of $f$ is restricted to the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ given by $\{x:x≥1\}$, then $f$ is one-to-one.

State the range of $f$ in this case.

Can anybody help me to solve this question?

Comment: A function is into if $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$

Comment: @Rememberme - you mean *one-to-one*, right ?

Comment: Yes yes I mean injective

Comment: Sorry, but nobody will understand your notation. Do you mean $x/(x^2+1)$ or $x/x^2+1$ or $x/(x\cdot 2) +1$ or $x/((x\cdot 2)+1)$? Please read the help page about formatting!

Comment: Now, what means $x/(x2+1)$? It could be $x/(x^2+1)$ or $x/(x\cdot 2 +1)$ ?

Comment: @Karl Yes the formatting is subpar, but I don't think anyone with poor formatting has ever denoted $2 \dot x$ as $x2$. It is pretty safe to assume that they just copy pasted it from some site and $x^2$ thus became $x2$.

Comment: @Soke, yes, you are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being injective (also badly termed one-to-one) for a function $f$ means that any equation $f(x)=c$ has *at most one* solution $x$, for any given value of$~c$. (A proper term would therefore be at-most-one-to-one.)

So just write down the equation $\frac x{x^2+1}=c$ for some fixed$~c$ and solve for $x$. The equation is equivalent to $cx^2-x+c=0$, which you can solve by the formula for the quadratic equation, provided that $c\neq0$ (for the case $c=0$ you have a linear equation, which indeed has a unique solution, so that specific case is OK). Now a quadratic equation rarely has a unique solution; here the discriminant is $1-4c^2$, which can be positive, zero, or negative. It is the positive values that cause a problem: for any $c\in(-\frac12,\frac12)$ with $c\neq0$ the discriminant is positive, and the equation $f(x)=c$ has *two* solutions; even having just one value of $c$ for which there is more than one solution would suffice to show that $f$ is not injective.

To see whether a restriction of $f$ is injective, you must show that for every $c$ there is at most one $x$ *in the restricted domain* that solves $f(x)=c$. For this purpose it is probably useful to actually write down the solution that the quadratic formula gives you, and to show that in case of multiple solutions, at least one solution is eliminated by the restriction.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If you are asking about
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}
$$
then consider the relation between $f(1/x)$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: Applause. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is not one to one, then if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, it is possible that $x_1 \neq x_2$.

So, we can start by saying,

$$ \dfrac{x_1}{x_1^2 + 1} = \dfrac{x_2}{x_2^2+1}$$
$$ x_1 x_2^2 + x_1 = x_2 x_1^2 + x_2$$
$$x_1x_2^2 - x_2x_1^2 = x_2 - x_1$$
$$ x_1x_2(x_2 - x_1) = x_2 - x_1$$
$$x_1x_2 = 1 $$

Hence, this can't be one to one.

Comment: That -1 is unfair. Actually the proof of @cgo is equivalent to the nice one of robjohn.

Comment: My guess is the fact that the argument starts by assuming the conclusion is what got the downvote. However, the order of the lines can be reversed, and then the proof seems good.

Comment: It is not impossible make as @cgo did and at the end to realize that is more elegant to do as you did (having in hand $x_1x_2$ = 1) . On the other hand, what our friend did is a typical proof by the absurdum and this is not at all forbidden. (By the way, when i wrote "equivalent" I wanted to write "the same"). Regards, Robjohn.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez (and cgo) The proof is not logically sound, sorry. It starts with $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and deduces $x_1 x_2 = 1$. This doesn't prove that $f$ is not injective; for that you would need to explicitly write that *if* $x_1 x_2 = 1$, *then* $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, *and* explicitly state that there exist $x_1 \neq x_2$ with $x_1 x_2 = 1$. Implications cannot always be reversed. When dealing with such an elementary question, you cannot afford to make logical shortcuts like that.

Comment: @Najib : A way to deduce the elegant condition given by Robjohn.....($x_1 x_2 = 1$ is an hyberbola obviously!)

Answer (score 0):

f(0) = 0; f(x) $\leq$ f(1) for all x; limf(x) = 0 when x tends to $\infty$. Hence for all number y of the open intervale (0, 1/2) there are two distinct numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ with f($x_1$) = f($x_2$) = y. Thus f is not one-to-one.